# AWK - Compare Two Files - If Field1 is Same, Compare Lines

Tags: awk

There are two files. When field1 is the same in both files,  compare the corresponding lines.  If they are exactly the same, then next.  If there are more or less line or if the contents are different, then echo field1.

In the example below, LSP1 and LSP2 have differences.  The differences are the total number of lines but it could also have been the contents of field2 and/or field3.  LSP3 is the same.  The desired output is below.

**File1**

```
LSP1    3.3.3.3 ae3.0
LSP1    5.5.5.5 ae2.0
LSP1    4.4.4.4 ae4.0
LSP1    7.7.7.7 ae1.0

LSP2    7.7.7.7 ae6.0
LSP2    3.3.3.3 ae4.0
LSP2    5.5.5.5 ae6.0
LSP2    4.4.4.4 ae1.0
LSP2    2.2.2.2 ae2.0

LSP3    5.5.5.5 ae4.0
LSP3    4.4.4.4 ae5.0
LSP3    7.7.7.7 ae3.0
```

**File2**

```
LSP1    3.3.3.3 ae3.0
LSP1    8.8.8.8 ae2.0
LSP1    4.4.4.4 ae4.0
LSP1    7.7.7.7 ae1.0
LSP1    2.2.2.2 ae2.0

LSP2    7.7.7.7 ae6.0
LSP2    3.3.3.3 ae1.0
LSP2    2.2.2.2 ae2.0

LSP3    5.5.5.5 ae4.0
LSP3    4.4.4.4 ae5.0
LSP3    7.7.7.7 ae3.0
```

**Output**

```
LSP1
LSP2
```

Comment: Please show us specific which part of the solution is a problem for you so we can help.

Comment: Are lines in input files sorted?

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46061929/edit) and I'll happily retract my close vote.

Comment: I could arrange them alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

With single ***awk***:

```
awk '{ k=$1 FS $2 FS $3 }NR==FNR && NF{ a[k]=$1; next }
     NF{ if(k in a) delete a[k]; else if(!b[$1]++) print $1 }
     END{ for(i in a) if(!(a[i] in b)) print a[i] }' file1 file2
```

The output:

```
LSP1
LSP2
```

Comment: Nice. Deleted mine.

Comment: You could use $0 as index in a and get rid of k.

Comment: @MarcLambrichs, that won't guarantee the equal quantity of whitespaces between the fields in each record. Don't do that in your approaches

Answer (score 0):

```
$ comm -3 file1 file2 | awk '$1 { print $1 }' | uniq
LSP1
LSP2
```

`comm -3` will output the lines that are only in `file1` *xor* in `file2`.

The `awk` script will extract column 1 from non-empty lines (whitespace-separated) and `uniq` will remove duplicates.

Note that `comm` assumes sorted input.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v RS= 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next} $0!=a[$1]{print $1}' file1 file2
LSP1
LSP2
```